# retrive data ( which is Time ) from Firebase and sort it

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN84r.png)
[RecylerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSpb9.png)

I'm developing an Android application using Firebase Database.

I have stored "time" (which provided by the user through TimePicker) in my database which is in String form. I'm retrieving the data from the database and displaying it into RecylerView (as you can see in the 2'nd image).  but want to sort it according to time (12:00 am to 11:59 pm).

Comment: Save date as timestamp instead it will be easy to sort .

Answer (score 0):

Using string to store dates is very inflexible.  It's only good if you want to display the date in the same format all the time.

The best way to store dates in Realtime Database is as a long integer.  If you do that, you can then easily query date ranges using those same integers.  You can also easily build dates to be converted to numbers, and use numbers to build date objects.

Dates are typically represented as the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch.  See also [Date.getTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime()), [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()), and [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html).